# Return dynamic relation based on date

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models, **course** and **courseDate**, for my courses i want to dynamically return a related object based on the next availabe date: `next_course_date`.

1 **course** has many **courseDates**.

This should return the next courseDate instance for each course.

Do i have to create a relationfield for that and alter the value with a method?

```
class Course(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Kurs"
        verbose_name_plural = "Kurse"

    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='courses', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='courses')

    next_course_date = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    access_level = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    banner = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class CourseDate(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Kurstermin"
        verbose_name_plural = "Kursetermine"

    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='course_dates', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='course_dates')
    lecturers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='main_lecturers')
    begin = models.DateTimeField()#not editable
    end = models.DateTimeField()#not editable
    date_details = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    access_level = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    published = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add a property to your Course returning the next available date? Assuming "next" course is defined by the `begin` field:

```
from dateime import datetime
class Course(models.Model):

    # your fields and meta

    @property
    def next_date(self):
        return CourseDate.objects.filter(begin__gte=datetime.today()).order_by('begin').first()
```

I added a filter for filtering out dates in the past. For each `Course` instance `course.next_date` would give you the next CourseDate instance from today on.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work as intended. I had function like this but they did not work because i did not know of the propery attribute.

Answer (score 0):

A ForeignKey relationship makes sense, then you can use Django querying itself to perform "Lookup that span relationships".

Check out this link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Hope this helps

Comment: I would need it in a method somehow to get the closest related object based on the date